# zf2 How to Select Where Like Upper case

Tags: zend-framework2

I trying to get some title from my database. But it doesn`t works:

```
$select->where->like('LOWER(title)','%'.$search_by.'%');
```

without LOWER it works fine.

```
$select->where->like('title','%'.$search_by.'%');
```

but I need LOWER case.

Comment: Are your DB tables using a case sensitive collation? If not, no need to lowercase!

Answer (score 3):

`like()` only seems to accept an identifier as its first parameter.

You should try this

```
$select->where->literal('LOWER(title) LIKE "%'.$search_by.'%"');
// or
$select->where->expression('LOWER(title) LIKE ?', '%'.$search_by.'%');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution (in ZF3) for people who searched for:

```
use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
$upperExpr = new Expression('LOWER(?)', [title], [Expression::TYPE_IDENTIFIER]);
$select->where->like($upperExpr, "%" . mb_strtolower($search_by, 'UTF-8') . "%");
```

Or only **strtolower()** if you have no 'äÄöÖüÜ' ;)

This will create the right SQL-Statement.